# How to find definition of Haskell function in VSCode?

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code

I'm learning Haskell, and some functions like `text` aren't easy to google. Look at this example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import Web.Spock
import Web.Spock.Config

import Control.Monad.Trans
import Data.IORef
import qualified Data.Text as T

data MySession = EmptySession
data MyAppState = DummyAppState (IORef Int)

main :: IO ()
main =
    do ref <- newIORef 0
       spockCfg <- defaultSpockCfg EmptySession PCNoDatabase (DummyAppState ref)
       runSpock 8080 (spock spockCfg app)

app :: SpockM () MySession MyAppState ()
app =
    do get root $ text "Hello World!"
       get ("hello" <//> var) $ \name ->
           do (DummyAppState ref) <- getState
              visitorNumber <- liftIO $ atomicModifyIORef' ref $ \i -> (i+1, i+1)
              text ("Hello " <> name <> ", you are visitor number " <> T.pack (show visitorNumber))
```

`do get root $ text "Hello World!"`

Normally, on VSCode, with any language, I would click on `text` with the rigth button, and "go to defintion". How do I find the definition of a function in VSCode?

I installed the `haskell.haskell` extension, and it didn't add this functionality.

Comment: I can't help you with VSCode, but since you mentioned Haskell names that are hard to google, let me instead suggest you try [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/).

Comment: Try installing https://github.com/haskell/haskell-language-server/

Comment: @arrowd HLS won't fix this issue because goto-definition in there doesn't work for libraries.